# C# IO.File.ReadAllBytes Path Problems

Tags: c#

I'm new here at this forum. I have a C# Problem with `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`. I read a filepath from a textbox like this C:\Users\Janek\Pictures\testpicture.

```
spath = tb_path.text;

System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(spath);
```

But that doesnt work. VisualStudio says that's a wrong path format. How can iI build a working path?.

```
spath = "@" + tb_path.text;

System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Didn't worked for me. It is certainly easy, but no matter what I try it does not work. But I think someone can help me here. Thanks for help!

Comment: What is in `spath` if you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: the second aproach `spath = "@" + tb_path.text;` will definately not work because this will result in an invalid path

Comment: What is the platform you are working on? Can you use a FileDialog? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Janek\\Pictures\\testpicture"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add "@" to the string, add it on the outside?

```
string path = tb_path.Text;

var x = File.ReadAllBytes(@path);
```

You want to escape like this : (@"C:\") not ("@C:\")

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears OK. The problem can be in the data you enter into the textbox instead. "C:\Users\Janek\Pictures\testpicture" can be a valid file name. but most likely it isn't, and you are missing a file extension. Something like

C:\Users\Janek\Pictures\testpicture.jpg

or

C:\Users\Janek\Pictures\testpicture.bmp

or

C:\Users\Janek\Pictures\testpicture.png

or whatever you file type is, is more likely to be correct.